# Showing model categories using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I wrote a model function to get categories and their sub categories using codeigniter. I want to display the full hierarchy in a single drop-down list.

```
Category
     sub1
       sub1.1
       sub1.2
     sub2
     sub3
        sub3.1
           sub3.1.1
        and so on.


MY model

     public function getCategoryTreeForParentId($parent_id = 0) {

      $categories = array();
      $this->db->from('jil_category');
      $this->db->where('ctg_parent', $parent_id);
      $result = $this->db->get()->result();
      foreach ($result as $mainCategory) {
        $category = array();
        $category['id'] = $mainCategory->ctg_id;
        $category['name'] = $mainCategory->ctg_name;
        $category['parent_id'] = $mainCategory->ctg_parent;
        $category['sub_categories'] = $this->getCategoryTreeForParentId($category['id']);
        $categories[$mainCategory->ctg_id] = $category;
      }
      return $categories;
    }
```

Comment: @PathikVejani thats not recursive. only get category and sub.

Comment: I used a clever library for showing and working with nested category trees MPTTree https://github.com/evgen359/nested-menu-for-codeigniter - maybe could help?

Comment: related - this course code has a very cool drag/drop system for hierarchal navigation that might help  https://github.com/joostvanveen/build-a-cms-with-codeigniter